# Integral Representation of Modified Bessel Function in Position-Space Feynman Propagator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator

I am working through a problem on deriving the explicit form of the position-space Feynman propagator. I have found, with thanks to many posts on this site, 2-3 different ways of performing the integrals over momenta to get $\Delta_{F}$ - all nice techniques. I am stuck on the last step of the last method. The step to be taken is the following:

\begin{align}
&= \int \frac{dk}{(2 \pi)^2} \frac{k}{r \sqrt{k^2 + m^2} + i \varepsilon} \sin kr , \\
&=\frac{m}{4 \pi^2 r + i \varepsilon} K_{1} (mr),
\end{align}
where $K_{1}$ is a modified Bessel function.

My first attempts at $u$-sub for $\sin kr$ and other such methods have come up short. I know there is an integral representation for modified Bessel functions as

\begin{equation}
K_{\nu} (x z) = \frac{\Gamma (\nu + \frac{1}{2}) (2 z)^{\nu}}{\pi^{1/2} x^{\nu}} \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\cos xt}{(t^2 + z^2)^{\nu + 1/2}} dt,
\end{equation}
which I am trying to massage the first expression into. I can't seem to find the right way to do it, or the above might be the wrong thing to convert to.

I have seen other ways of putting the position-space propagator into integral forms of $K_{1}$ and I understand them; m**y question is I specifically want to know how to massage the above integral into a function $K_{1}$**.

Comment: Integrate by parts

Comment: Okay I can see that, as in this post - https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/672184 - but  I can't seem to get rid of the bit of the IBP that doesn't contain an integration, i.e., the $uv$ from $\int u dv = uv - \int v du$. The $\cos(kr)$ factor plays up at $k_{2} =\infty$ and at $k_{1} = 0$ the integral evaluates to 1.

Comment: You can find a detailed explanation in my notes https://hepnotes.files.wordpress.com/2021/11/qft-miscellaneous-topics-1.pdf page 242-244