# Integration step when deriving position-space expression of Feynman propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I am looking at the various ways to derive explicit position-space expressions of the Green's function with certain boundary conditions (Feynman propagator) of the Klein-Gordon equation. In this particular example, I cannot figure out why, when integrating by parts, the boundary term, i.e., the $uv$ in $\int u dv = u v - \int v du$, disappears. The result of the whole process is, as usual, a modified Bessel function. I know there are multiple different methods to perform this integration; I understand these and am not interested., i.e., through contour integration, or Schwinger parameterization, I specifically want to know why, on the second line on the below, that we discard the evaluated term from the IBP?

See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/672184/2451) Phys.SE answer:

[image: Method of the integration]

Whenever I try I get something like

\begin{equation}
uv = \left[ \left( -\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2 + m^2}} \right) \cos kr \right]^{\infty}_{0} = [-1\cdot \cos\infty] + 0. 
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you have correctly identified that this argument is just mathematically nonsense. We often discard terms that are multiplied by sinusoidal functions of infinity, but it is not mathematically rigorously proved. You are better off taking the contour integration.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Okay, good to know. Like you said the contour integration, among others, makes much more sense. But this particular derivation has been nagging at me. Thank you.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent - In the present context, dropping terms like $\cos \infty$ is perfectly consistent. All computations are to be understood to be true only within normalizable wave-packet states. For all such states, infinity oscillating functions such as "$\cos\infty$" vanish due to the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: I recommend repeating the calculation with an $e^{-mr}$ factor for rigour before you take $m\to0^+$, or some other regularisation you prefer.